# decoded snort logs

Tags: security, logging, file-format, logfile, snort

I used this command :

```
$ snort -b -l /home/username/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs
```

to log snort packets, but it give me ASCII format ..

I want the log file in a normal text format,How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Snort stores packets in packet format only. Your situation is that you opened the packet as an text editor.

Comment: If snort is connected to the DB, only the data area except the packet header can be stored in hexadecimal. The hexadecimal of the data area can be decoded into readable text.

Comment: I want to send the logs into hadoop mapreduce to count the packet, so it must be text right ? when i open the log in hadoop it appears as unreadable character.. so what should i do to make the log able to count?

Comment: I don't know what you want. What do you want to know among Hadoop and Snort? If do you wnat to know about hadoop, send human readable data into  hadoop. If do you want to know about snort, open log by packet dump tools like wireshark. If do you want to know about all of both, packetpig maybe helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Or if use this command 'snort -b -l /home/username/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs `-K ascii`', Only the packet header is stored as readable text. But if store the packet header only, Snort is useless.

Comment: I want to know how to translate the snort Ascii log file into readable text .. if i cant then how can i use it in hadoop ? i want to use java programming with this log file which mean i need it as a text .. is this even possible ?  Sorry im totally new to snort and hadoop and i dont know is this can be done or not.Thanks for answering me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use hadoop for analyze snort, first you need to upload after convert the snort logs to readable text.
I decoded snort logs that stored in the mysql whenever necessary. As below php code is my decoding tools

[rawdata_up.php]

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
<script lang="javascript">
function checkInput (form) {
 if(!(form.userfile.value)) {
            alert("choice file");
            form.userfile.focus();
        return;
    }

myChoices.submit();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name=myChoices method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="rawdata_post.php?TyPe=<?$TyPe?>">
<table width="802" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<tr><td bgcolor="#8080FF">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="800" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#CFD0ED"><b>Mass Rawdata Decoding Page</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FAFAEE"></td>
</tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FAFAEE"><font size=2><b>File</b></font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FAFAEE">
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="60"></td>
          <td style='padding-left:10px;'bgcolor=#FAFAEE>
                <select name=TyPe>
                <option value='A'>HEX</option>
                <option value='B'>URL</option>
                </select>
                </td>
</tr>
<td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="CFD0ED">
<font size=2>
<input type="button" value="Decode" onclick="checkInput(this.form)">
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
<table align="center"><a href=http://localhost/index.html>home</a></table>
</html>
```

[rawdata_post.php]

```
<table border=1 cellspacing=1 bgcolor=black>
<?
function hex2bin($hexdata) {
  $bindata="";

  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($hexdata);$i+=2) {
    $bindata.=chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata,$i,2)));
  }

  return $bindata;
}
#####uploaded file directory####
$TyPe = $HTTP_POST_VARS["TyPe"];
#$uploaddir = 'rawdata_tmp/';
$uploaddir = '../../PHP/phptemp/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$userfile_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
print "<pre>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

#$csv_file = "rawdata_tmp/$userfile_name";
$csv_file = "../../PHP/phptemp/$userfile_name";
 $fp = fopen ("$csv_file","r");
        while ($line = fgetcsv($fp,100000,","))
         {
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($line) ; $i++) {
                $field_[$i] = $line[$i] ;
                $STR = hex2bin($field_[$i]);
                $STR2=$field_[$i];
                if ($TyPe=='A'){
                $STR=htmlspecialchars($STR);
        ?>
<tr bgcolor=white><td>
        <?
                echo $STR;
        ?>
</td></tr>  
        <?
                }else{
                $STR2=urldecode("$STR2");
                $STR2=htmlspecialchars($STR2);
        ?>
<tr bgcolor=white><td>
        <?
                echo $STR2;
        ?>
</td></tr>
        <?
                }
                }
        }
        fclose($fp);
} else {
 print "upload fail~~\n";
 print_r($_FILES);
}
print "</pre>";
?>
</table>
<title>
<?
echo $userfile_name
?>
</title>
<a href=http://localhost/index.html>home</a></table>
```

Good luck~

Comment: Can you tell me please where to use this code ? do i need to install web server, mysql ,or just put it in a file or command prompt? or i should rewrite it into java code ?
Aslo  do i use both (rawdata_up.php) and (rawdata_post.php) methods in the same place together ?

Comment: last question, is this code convert just specific log file or all the logs ?

Comment: If snort is connected to the mysql, pcap log can be stored in hexadecimal(data_payload field of the data table). And this php code can decode hexadecimal. Just used by web servers like apache that support php. Then you can apply it.